# Haskell Calling a function as an argument of another function

Tags: haskell

I have a function that sorts through a `[Film]` and creates a list of those with the specified `d`, `fnSortD`.

I have another function that calculates the average `r` of a film `fnAvg`.

Now I need to find the average of all the average ratings for all films with `d`.

I thought to start this by making another function that creates a list of all average ratings for all the films with `d`: `fnLR :: String -> [Film] -> [Float]` so that I could then easily get the average of *them* with another function.

This is where i'm stuck, the list of films I want to use as the argument for `fnLR` is the output of the other function, fnSortD, and I can't figure out for the life of me how to use that as the input argument, whilst also being able to separate the film datatype into its variable definitions.

I hope this question isn't too confusing, it's certainly confusing me.

Comment: Show the portion of your code related to your question.

Comment: Sorry, it sorts through the list for a specific `d`, so only Films with `d` are in that list.

Comment: What's the `dir` param for if you don't use it to calculate anything?

Comment: Sorry, it's relevant in other functions I just didn't take it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've actually asked is solvable trivially:

```
fnListAvgRatings :: [Film] -> [Float]
fnListAvgRatings = map fnAvg . fnSortD
```

The above body is the same as:

```
fnListAvgRatings films = map fnAvg (fnSortD films)
```

since

```
map fnAvg (fnSortD films) = (map fnAvg . fnSortD) films
```

I've dopped the `dir` parameter because it wasn't doing anything.

Now since that function is so trivial that it's body takes as many symbols as it's title I wouldn't even bother declaring it if I were you.

Comment: I now get a type error, as fnSortD is type String -> [Film] -> [Float], but it the expected type is [Film] -> [Film]